# String won't store more than one word (C)

Tags: arrays, c, string, cs50

This is the first step in a program I have written.

**The objective**: A user needs to write a sentence, and my program needs to store it in an array. This can be as short or long as they like.

**My program**: Runs with no technical errors

**The issue**: When I run the program, I am unable to submit anything more than 1 word. 'Hello' submits and the program executes. Anything more than that - new words, spaces, punctuation and numbers, when I hit enter - I just keep jumping to a new line in my terminal and the program doesn't go to the next step.

This is the code I am using to

1. Prompt the user for text and
2. Store the answer.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
    
int main(void)
{
    string z = get_string("Text: \n");
    
    //  int n = strlen(z);
    
    int a = 0;
    int d = 1;
    int e = 0;
    
    while (z[a] != '\0')
    {
        while (isalpha(z[a]))
        {
            a++;
        }
    
        while (z[a] ==' ')
        {
            d++;
        }
    
        //Count the sentences
    
        while (z[a] == '.' || z[a] == '!' || z[a] == '?' || z[a] == '/')
        {
            e++;
        }
    }
    
    // printf("%i letter(s)\n", a);
    // printf("%i word(s)\n", d);
    // printf("%i sentence(s)\n", e);
    
    //Coleman-Liau index formula
    
    int m = (0.0588 * (100 * a / d) - 0.206 * (100 * e / d) - 15.8);
    
    if (m <= 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
    
    if (m >= 16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }
    
    if (m < 16)
    {
        printf("Grade %i\n", m);
    }
}
```

Pretty new to coding and any help will be appreciated!

Screenshot of my terminal

[image: Screenshot of my terminal]

Comment: Is that the CS50 `get_string()` or is it a function you wrote?

Comment: What is the "next step" that isn't working?

Comment: Hey there! That is a CS50 function :) The full program works like this, but I can't get passed step 1 when I run it with more than one word:

1. Get input from user
2. Count the characters in the input
2. Count the words in the input
3. Count the sentences in the input
5. Apply the Coleman Liau Index formula
6. Print what Grade that user is

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. When you press Enter, it's supposed to go to a new line in your terminal. Put `printf("%s\n", z);` after that line, you should see the line you typed.

Comment: Yes exactly - if I use printf, then I am able to submit a sentence. If I don't, I just keep hitting enter and nothing happens.

Comment: Show your code in the question.  You should create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Note "minimal" and "short" — it only needs to contain the code which reads the string and prints the result.  Note that it must also reproduce your problem — you may need to keep a loop or whatever.

Comment: @AnnikaduToit It sounds like your program is going into a loop after it reads the input. Without seeing the rest of the program, we can't tell.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can easily copy&paste plain text from your terminal into your question. No need to make a screenshot and add the output as graphics.

Comment: I think you are saying you want to be able to read more than one sentence and keep processing as long as you enter data? If that is the case, you need `get_string()` within the loop, otherwise you never read more than one line. (you can check `strlen(z) == 0` as an exit condition to break the output loop when you press [Enter] without input) You do know that `get_string()` stops reading when it reaches the end of a line -- right?

Comment: Should `int m = (0.0588 * (100 * a / d) - 0.206 * (100 * e / d) - 15.8);` be `double` instead of `int`. Example `"Hello"` and Grade `13.6` instead of just `13`? Using `int` to truncate to `13` is common, but also a common mistake. Since this is for a `"Coleman-Liau index formula"` `int` may well be correct -- double check.

Comment: while (z[a] ==' ')
        {
            d++;
        } will never stop if z[a] == ' '

Comment: Well presented first time question.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the while loops that count words and sentences never increment `a`, which is the index into `z`. So they keep testing the same character over and over and you're in an infinite loop.

It works for a single word because those tests never succeed in the first place.

You also shouldn't be using the variable that counts letters as the array index.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
    
int main(void)
{
    
    char *z = get_string("Text: \n");
    
    //  int n = strlen(z);
    
    int i = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int d = 1;
    int e = 0;
    
    while (z[i] != '\0')
    {
        int counted = 0;
        while (isalpha(z[i]))
        {
            a++;
            i++;
            counted = 1;
        }
    
        while (z[i] ==' ')
        {
            d++;
            i++;
            counted = 1;
        }
    
        //Count the sentences
    
        while (z[i] == '.' || z[i] == '!' || z[i] == '?' || z[i] == '/')
        {
            e++;
            i++;
            counted = 1;
        }
        if (!counted) {
            i++;
        }
    }
    
    // printf("%i letter(s)\n", a);
    // printf("%i word(s)\n", d);
    // printf("%i sentence(s)\n", e);
    
    //Coleman-Liau index formula
    
    int m = (0.0588 * (100 * a / d) - 0.206 * (100 * e / d) - 15.8);
    
    if (m <= 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
    
    if (m >= 16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }
    
    if (m < 16)
    {
        printf("Grade %i\n", m);
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (z[i] != '\0')` loops forever should none of the nested 3 `while` loops enter.

Comment: Good catch, I added a variable to check for that case.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles using: *gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled2.c" -o "untitled2.o"*
2. performs the desired functionality
3. uses meaningful variable names
4. uses a unique variable name for stepping through the text
5. does not include header files those contents are not used
6. uses a `for()` loop for stepping through the text
7. uses `size_t` rather than `int` variables because the contents of those variables will never be <0

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <string.h>
//#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
    
int main(void)
{
    string z = get_string("Text: \n");
    
    size_t spaces = 0;
    size_t sentences = 0;
    size_t letters = 0;
    
    for( size_t i = 0; z[i]; i++ )
    { 
        if( z[i] ==' ' )
        {
            spaces++;
        }
        
        if( isalpha( z[i] ) )
        {
            letters++;
        }
    
        //Count the sentences
    
        if( z[i] == '.' || z[i] == '!' || z[i] == '?' || z[i] == '/')
        {
            sentences++;
        }
    }
    
    // printf("%i letter(s)\n", a);
    // printf("%i word(s)\n", d);
    // printf("%i sentence(s)\n", e);
    
    //Coleman-Liau index formula
    
    int m = (int)(0.0588 * (double)(100 * letters / spaces) - 0.206 * (double)(100 * sentences / spaces) - 15.8);
    
    if (m <= 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
    
    if (m >= 16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }
    
    if (m < 16)
    {
        printf("Grade %i\n", m);
    }
}
```

a typical run of the program:

```
Text: 
a quick brown fox jumped over a lazy dog
Grade 7
```